# Coyping by reference issue in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok i thought i had it figured out but i guess i was wrong. I previously posted the issue where because javascript an object is copied as a reference of the original, changes to the original object will also be reflected in the copy. So based on the recommendations of using

```
const originalData = {...docid[0][0].Record}
// or
const originalData = Object.assign({}, docid[0][0].Record)
```

i revised my code to use them with not much luck. My code looks now like this..

```
 // Assign the Data from query
 // const originalData = {...docid[0][0].Record}
 const originalData = Object.assign({}, docid[0][0].Record)
 // Delete the History & DocId Object from Data Object
 delete originalData['History']
 delete originalData['DocId']
```

and if i print to console.log(originalData) the data is correct. Now in my code i
update some data and have a function that compares the data to create a diff file
so that's why i need the originalData.

After i run this below code which takes my new data and map's it , removes the undefined etc

```
 // Mailing Address
 let MailingAddrObj = update.mailingAddress
 Object.keys(MailingAddrObj).forEach(key => MailingAddrObj[key] === undefined && delete MailingAddrObj[key])
 let MailingAddress = _.extend(docid[0][0].Record.mailingAddress, MailingAddrObj)
```

but for some reason the last command also modify's my originalData which i thought was either deep copy and that should not happen. So if i print the originalData after this code it reflects the new data in the MailingAddress object.

So what am i missing here or what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign` will not work for deep clone. use like this

```
const originalData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(docid[0][0].Record));
```

Comment: Is that the only way to deep clone by stringify and parse, wondering how efficient it is.

Comment: its most efficient. see example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#warning_for_deep_clone)

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more searching, i found a solution based on lodash which looks cleaner to me specially as i use already lodash in my code.

```
const _ = require('lodash');
var obj = [{  x: 1 }, {y: 2}];
  // Deep copy
var deepCopy = _.cloneDeep(obj);
```